# TransferText to copy a csv file into a temp table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have to copy a csv file into Access , the file keeps changing dynamically so had stored the file into a temp file and then read from it. It worked fine in Access 2010 however Access 2013 throws an error "could not find the temp table".

This is what was already working:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "DLPTemp3", filename, True.
```

The DLPtemp3 is the temp table.

```
 Dim ImportIdx As Integer, Rs1 As ADODB.Recordset, str1 As String, Str2 As String, str3 As String, a As Currency
   ImportIdx = InStr(1, Me.txtEbayPath, "csv")             
        If ImportIdx = 0 Then
             DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "DLPTemp3", filename, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid file format."
        End If

   Set Rs1 = mdbx.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DLPTemp3;", SeeChangesReadWrite)

  If Rs1.Fields.Item(17).Name = "Postage and packaging" Then
    DoCmd.Close acTable, "DLPTemp3"
    mdbx.Execute ("DROP TABLE DLPTemp3")
  End If
```

It throws 'Invalid object DLPTemp3.' I tried to declare it as a global variable but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: hi, wich line trows the error ?

Comment: Hi Luis, It throws error on the transfertext line  DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "DLPTemp3", filename, True.

Comment: Table DLPTemp3 actually exist in your DB?

Comment: No its a temp table so just declared it as  Dim tempTableName As String
    tempTableName = "DLPTemp3"

Comment: You should create destination table before import.

Comment: TransferText creates new table. What worked in 2010 should work in 2013, but I am still using 2010 so maybe something has changed. You state two error messages, which one is actual issue? Don't see `mdbx` declared and set.

Comment: You declare Rs1 as ADODB recordset yet use DAO method to set.